# Check whether the statement true or false? Prove or disprove it.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity

***Check whether the statement true or false?***

> Suppose $f$ is continuously differentiable functions on $\mathbb{R}$,
>   $f(x)\rightarrow 1$ and $f'(x)\rightarrow b$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$. Then value of $b=1$.

I tried to apply L'Hospital's rule, I failed to apply. Can you please give hints?

Comment: Those limits are for $x\to\infty$ I suppose. If that's the case then $b=0$.

Comment: I applied  L' Hospital's rule to this function. $g(x)=e^{x}log(f(x)$

Comment: Hello copper.hat I have edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $b>0$ then for some $L$ we have $f'(x) \ge {1 \over 2} b$ for
$x \ge L$ and the mean value theorem shows that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$. A similar analysis applies if $b <0$. Hence we must have $b=0$.

Comment: How do you apply mean value theorem? for which interval?

Comment: Take some $x_0 \ge L$, then for any $x \ge x_0$ there is some $\xi \in (x,x_0)$ such that $f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(\xi)(x-x_0) \ge f(x_0) + {1 \over 2} b (x-x_0)$. Hence $f$ is unbounded above.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample:

$f(x) = e^{-x} +1;$

$f'(x) = -e^{-x} ;$

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 1.$

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f'(x) = 0.$